# My cache is being flushed, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having some problem with my app cache being flushed (page, action and fragment cache).

It looks like (according to the memcached IRC and the logfiles) the cache is being flushed very often, even though the cache isn't full.

I'm using:

- memcached 1.4.5
- rails 3.1.0.rc6
- [dalli 1.0.5](https://github.com/mperham/dalli)

[Here is data](https://gist.github.com/1169246) being printed when running `stats` using telnet.

I'm not using any `expires_in` options when saving data to the cache.
Instead I use sweepers to flush the cache manually every night.

Anyone got an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're running out of memcached space:

```
STAT limit_maxbytes 262144000
STAT bytes          209406773
```

...causing data to be evicted from the cache when you don't want it to and the stats show that:

```
STAT evictions 94777
```

Looks like you've configured a 250mb cache size and you're using 80-90%.

Try increasing the cache size via -m option.

**UPDATE:**

The stats also show your cache being manually flushed via **Rails.cache.clear** (sending memcached **flush_all**):

```
STAT cmd_flush 4317 # Original Stat Capture
STAT cmd_flush 48   # New Stat Capture
```

You should search your codebase for manual cache flushes.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I increased it to 550 MB.

Comment: Give me another 24h :) I'm having some problems with my rails app.

Comment: It's the same thing. Here is the new memcached stats log: https://gist.github.com/1187186

Comment: It looks like you solved the original eviction problem, not sure what you're experiencing now.  New log shows 0 evictions with more memory.

Comment: The problem is still that the fragment cache being generated at night using a rake task, isn't being active for more then a couple of hours. Watching the log file when entering a page that should be cached shows that the cache is being regenerated. I've no idea why...

Comment: Something in the app is issuing a flush command to memcached which drops the entire cache contents.  Your most recent stats show that it has happened 48 times.  This is highly unusual.

Comment: Does `Rails.cache.reset` flushes everything in memcache, or just it's own cache?

Comment: For a Dalli cache instance it just resets the connection.  Look for Rails.cache.clear or similar.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is, but you tried to help and almost solved the problem so I'll give you the 50 rep. Thanks.